# Problems generating T4 from command line with TextTransform.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4

I'm running the command with the following options:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\TextTransform.exe" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes" -a !!NamespaceHint!MyNamespace -dp T4VSHost!Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.Directives.FallbackT4VSHostProcessor!"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll"
-P "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies" "MyTemplate.tt"
```

And this the error I'm getting:

```
error : An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\EnvDTE'.
Nombre de archivo: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\EnvDTE'
   at  System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at  System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at  System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at  Roslyn.Utilities.FileUtilities.OpenFileStream(String path)
   at  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(String path, MetadataReferenceProperties properties, DocumentationProvider documentation)
   at  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.<>c.<.ctor>b__15_0(String x)
   at  System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at  System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__67`1.MoveNext()
   at  System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__67`1.MoveNext()
   at  System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at  System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at  System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray.CreateRange[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ImmutableArrayExtensions.AsImmutableOrEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.ValidateReferences[T](IEnumerable`1 references)
   at  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.WithReferences(IEnumerable`1 references)
   at  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.CommonWithReferences(IEnumerable`1 newReferences)
```

However, inside the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies** I have these contents:

[image]

The header of the .tt file has the following code:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE80" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE80" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs"#>
```

How can I fix the problem?

By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

Comment: `EnvDTE` is not `envdte.dll`. Where that file name is coming from is another matter. FWIW, on my system this runs without error with VS 2019 Professional on an empty `MyTemplate.tt` (if I use `TextTransform.exe` from a VS command prompt without qualifying the path). Check what's actually in the `.tt`.

Comment: Read remarks at bottom of the page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: @jdweng How do I do that?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Please check the updated OP. I've included the header of the T4 file. Thanks

Comment: On my system it actually errors  out on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0` and not `EnvDTE` -- if I change the assembly reference in the file to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll` it works. Looks like something funky is going on with assembly name resolution.

Comment: Aren't you using VS 19, not 15?

Comment: @jdweng: Microsoft loves its codenames -- Windows 8 isn't version 8 either. Visual Studio 2019 is actually version 16; version 15 is Visual Studio 2017. Nevertheless, even 2019 includes a `Shell.15.0` file. You may still be on to something in the sense that referencing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell` (no version number) works on my machine.